# How to change a column position in a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I was wondering if it is possible to change the position of a column in a dataframe, actually to change the schema?

Precisely if I have got a dataframe like `[field1, field2, field3]`, and I would like to get `[field1, field3, field2]`.

I can't put any piece of code. 
Let us imagine we're working with a dataframe with one hundred columns, after some joins and transformations, some of these columns are misplaced regarding the schema of the destination table.

How to move one or several columns, i.e: how to change the schema?

Comment: Dataframes are immutable, so whatever you do will be returning a new one anyway.  In most cases I would think you could avoid doing this though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, i have to put my data in a table and after some joins and transformations, the column's order become different. That's why, i need to get the good schema to write into the table.

Comment: It still doesn't explain what you really want. Order is not particularly valuable in general since you refer to columns by name anyway.

Comment: Order is important because some DataFrame operations depend on order. For example, `df.write.insertInto(table)` behaves like a SQL insert statement and matches data frame columns to the output SQL columns by position, not by name.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get the column names, reorder them however you want, and then use `select` on the original DataFrame to get a new one with this new order:

```
val columns: Array[String] = dataFrame.columns
val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = ??? // do the reordering you want
val result: DataFrame = dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNames.head, reorderedColumnNames.tail: _*)
```

Comment: This solution does not match with dynamic columns in a DataFrame.

Comment: I have 500+ columns in dataframe, using this approach I suspect that my performance is degraded on a large scale.  Does reordering of dataframe's column really degrade the performance?

Comment: how do you do this in java? especially the ```.tail: _* part```. I found it is so difficult to create even the Array of string in java.

Comment: In Java, it would be something like `dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNames[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(reorderedColumnNames, 1, reorderedColumnNames.length)`, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)

Answer (score 9):

The [spark-daria](https://github.com/mrpowers/spark-daria) library has a `reorderColumns` method that makes it easy to reorder the columns in a DataFrame.

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.DataFrameExt._

val actualDF = sourceDF.reorderColumns(
  Seq("field1", "field3", "field2")
)
```

The `reorderColumns` method uses @Rockie Yang's solution under the hood.

If you want to get the column ordering of `df1` to equal the column ordering of `df2`, something like this should work better than hardcoding all the columns:

```
df1.reorderColumns(df2.columns)
```

The [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria) library also defines a `sortColumns` transformation to sort columns in ascending or descending order (if you don't want to specify all the column in a sequence).

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.transformations._

df.transform(sortColumns("asc"))
```

Answer (score 7):

Like others have commented, I'm curious to know why would you do this as the order is not relevant when you can query the columns by their names.

Anyway, using a select should give the feeling the columns have moved in schema description:

```
val data = Seq(
  ("a",       "hello", 1),
  ("b",       "spark", 2)
)
.toDF("field1", "field2", "field3")

data
 .show()

data
 .select("field3", "field2", "field1")
 .show()
```

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but when using the .write method to add a partition to the hive table, it seems to write by position and not by name. I would be very happy in that case :)

Comment: When you use SparkContext.union, the RDD-based union will ignore the schema, so in that case column order needs to be overridden.

Comment: Unions. Order matters, even if the columns are all the same. I had a case class set as the schema on two datasets, but with different column ordering. Had to set the ordering to match for the union to work.

Comment: @BrianBarker, good example. Worse is that in most SQL contexts a union will work solely based on number of columns and the type of the columns. So if the wrong columns are aligned yet datatypes match, it can appear to succeed yet silently mangle the data, column names end up as those of the first dataset.

Answer (score 7):

A tiny different version compare to @Tzach Zohar

```
val cols = df.columns.map(df(_)).reverse
val reversedColDF = df.select(cols:_*)
```

Answer (score 7):

for any dynamic frame, firstly convert dynamic frame to data frame to use standard pyspark functions

```
data_frame = dynamic_frame.toDF()
```

Now, rearrange columns to new data frame using select function operation.

```
data_frame_temp = data_frame.select(["col_5","col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Spark Scala Example:**

Let's assume a you have a dataframe `demo_df` and it has following column set:
`id, salary, country, city, firstname, lastname`
and you want to rearrange its sequence.

**demo_df**
[image: demo_df_screenshot]

Select all the column(s) and drop those column(s) you want to rearrange.
I have removed 'salary, country, city' columns from the list of columns.

`val restcols = demo_df.columns.diff(Seq("salary", "country", "city"))`

Now rearrange the column name(s) according to your requirement and append or prepend to the remaining column(s)
**Example to prepend the column(s)**
`val all_cols = Seq($"salary", $"city", $"country") ++: restcols.map(col(_))`

Now select the dataframe and provide the newly defined column list
`demo_df.select(all_cols: _*).show()`
[image]

**Example to append the column(s)**
`val all_cols = restcols.map(col(_)) ++ Seq($"salary", $"city", $"country")` 
`demo_df.select(all_cols: _*).show()`
[image]

Hope it helps. Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do in pyspark:

As with MySQL queries, you can re-select and pass in the desired column order to the parameters, returning the same order as you passed in the query parameters.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = [
    {'id': 1, 'sex': 1, 'name': 'foo', 'age': 13},
    {'id': 1, 'sex': 0, 'name': 'bar', 'age': 12},
]

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# init df
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

The output is as follows

```
+---+---+----+---+
|age| id|name|sex|
+---+---+----+---+
| 13|  1| foo|  1|
| 12|  1| bar|  0|
+---+---+----+---+
```

Pass in the column position order you want as an argument to select

```
# change columns position
df = df.select(df.id, df.name, df.age, df.sex)
df.show()
```

The output is as follows

```
+---+----+---+---+
| id|name|age|sex|
+---+----+---+---+
|  1| foo| 13|  1|
|  1| bar| 12|  0|
+---+----+---+---+
```

I hope I can help you.