# Java Spark, Using a nested JSON to create dataset reorders columns

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I'm running into an issue where I need to create a dataset in Java Spark Using a JSON file and then output the contents to a parquet file.

The problem I'm having is that the parquet file needs to have a specific schema and the dataset from the JSON reorders the data alphabetically and does this for the nested section of the JSON as well. I know I can use select and then specify the columns in the needed order. My problem has to do with the reording of the nested columns aNested and bNested specifically. How do I select the nested fields to reorder them to match the final needed parquet output schema?

JSON dataset schema:

```
|-- a: string (nullable = true)
|-- b: array (nullable = true)
|     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |     |-- aNested: string (nullable = true)
|     |     |-- bNested: long (nullable = true)
|     |     |-- cNested: long (nullable = true)
|-- cDate: string(nullable = true)
```

Needed Final parquet schema:

```
|-- a: string (nullable = true)
|-- b: array (nullable = true)
|     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |     |-- cNested: long (nullable = true)
|     |     |-- aNested: long (nullable = true)
|     |     |-- bNested: string (nullable = true)
|-- cDate: string(nullable = true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104600/how-to-change-a-column-position-in-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the link! It looks like it works for non nested elements, I'm looking for the same thing except including the nested fields in the dataset. I'm not sure how I'd reference and reorder those

Comment: I think the link would work for the use case that you have mentioned above. If you mean to say something else, can you please update the question accordingly?

Comment: I updated the question to specifically ask about the reordering of the nested dataset fields

Comment: Can you also please provide the corresponding example. The example you have specified does not a disorder of nested fields

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated the example, in the JSON dataset the nested fields are ordered as aNested, bNested and cNested. I need to change the order so it'd be something like cNested, aNested, bNested.

Comment: It dosent matter if the columns are reordered within the same hierarchy. Since JSON and parquet are semi structured, it is not necessary to maintian order nor necessaily contain all columns. Just go ahead and write the JSON file as Parquet and you are good to go. Let us know incase you face error while reading the parquet file after writing! Happy coding!